expl3 how to expand float and not enclosing macro
I wish to get to my \g_wp_efforts_tl variable which I subsequently use for creating table row the following
(1) \tl_gput_right:Nn \g_wp_efforts_tl {\lead@style { \fp_to_tl:N \g_effort_fp } }
unfortunatelly if I subsequently change variable \g_effort_fp and then insert
(2) \tl_gput_right:Nx \g_wp_efforts_tl {\fp_to_tl:N \g_effort_fp}
Then on evaluation it will use new value also for evaluating row (1). How to avoid that. I have tried so far
                \tl_gput_right:Nn \g_wp_efforts_tl {\lead@style}
                \tl_gput_right:NN \g_wp_efforts_tl \c_group_begin_token
                \tl_gput_right:Nx \g_wp_efforts_tl {\fp_to_tl:N \g_effort_fp }
                \tl_gput_right:NN \g_wp_efforts_tl \c_group_end_token

But it just generates errors.
Actually the following works well, another approach with accepted answer
                \tl_gput_right:Nn \g_wp_efforts_tl {\lead@style}
                \tl_gput_right:Nx \g_wp_efforts_tl {{\fp_to_tl:N \g_effort_fp}}


it's very hard to guess what you did or what output you expected if you just past fragments. please post a complete small test document and say what result you expect from the test

if \lead@style is a macro taking an argument to be used as \lead@style{foo} then you can not use \c_group_begin_token that is the wrong kind of brace, just as you can not use \section \bgroup foo\egroup  you need \section{foo}

I would guess you want
\tl_gput_right:Ne \g_wp_efforts_tl {\exp_not:N\lead@style { \fp_to_tl:N \g_effort_fp } }

To use e expansion, but preventing the expansion of \lead@style
but without any example in your question it is hard to be sure.

For me works                 \tl_gput_right:Nx \g_wp_efforts_tl {\exp_not:N\lead@style { \fp_to_tl:N \g_effort_fp } } it says that Ne variant does not exists.

@VojtaK you have an old latex then (but x is OK here)
